# Can 'civi version' show release candidates?

Tags: sysadmin

We have a bash update script that gets all released versions with `civi version` command but how do I find the release candidates?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the number or the tar file? If the tar file you can just do e.g. https://download.civicrm.org/latest/civicrm-RC-drupal.tar.gz (see https://download.civicrm.org/latest/)

Comment: you're right Dave the RC is always the RC! I'm trying to wget the archive so I don't need more